# I want that onPressed method in IconButton return a new Container

Tags: dart, flutter

In my flutter app, i want that when i press a IconButton, the app show the image that i click in a new container.
This is my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          0 < favorites.length
              ? IconButton(
                  icon: Image.network(favorites[0]),
                  onPressed: (){
                      return new Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(favorites[0])
                          ],
                        ),
                      );

                  },
                )
              : Container(),
        ]));
```

}

i want that image that i click show up in the black rectangle:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqOYa.png

Comment: Could you describe what exactly do you want to show on screen? (or better - to add screenshot)

Comment: Done! i already add a screenshot!

Comment: I've posted answer

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `onPressed` is just ignored.

```
final VoidCallback onPressed;
```

returning from a callback passed around does **not** return the enclosing function (`build()`) and therefore returning the container won't have any effect.

What you rather want is something like

```
   onPressed: () {
     setState(() {isPressed = true;})
   }

   bool isPressed = false;

   build() {
     if(isPressed) {
       return new Container(
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             Image.network(favorites[0])
           ],
         ),
       );
     } else {
       return /* as you have it in your question */
     }
   }
```

Calling `setState()` will cause `build()` to be executed again and there you can check the flat `isPressed` (or perhaps better name it `wasPressed`) and return different content this time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like:

```
  List<String> favorites;
  String selectedIcon;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(children: favorites.map((String src) => IconButton(
          icon: Image.network(src),
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              selectedIcon = src;
            });
          },
        )).toList(),),
        Container(
          child: Image.network(selectedIcon),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

There are no alignment, styles, decoration in this code, I think you can add what you need by yourself